# Is that possible to change decimal value to integer value (0) whenever result value is "0.00"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Whenever result value is "0.00" it should display "0" otherwise result.
when I am trying to use case statement it is displaying same result.is that possible to change decimal value to integer value whenever result value is "0.00"?

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (ID int identity(1,1),Credit decimal(10,2),Debit decimal(10,2),Result decimal(10,2),ExpectedOP VARCHAR(20))
        insert into @Test (Credit,Debit,ExpectedOP)
        select 10,5,'2.00' union
        select 0,2,'0' union
        select 5,6,'0.83'

        update @Test SET Result=Credit/Debit
        select *,CASE WHEN Result=0 THEN 0 ELSE Result END Currentop from @Test
```

[image]

Comment: No you can't mix datatypes in a single column. But honestly this is a display issue and should be handled in the front end, not the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are limited to converting it to a string. This should be handled in the front end anyway.

```
    select *,CASE WHEN Result=0 THEN CAST(0 as nvarchar(MAX)) ELSE cast(Result as nvarchar(Max)) END Currentop from @Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this output helps. **Check the newCredit** Column

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (ID int identity(1,1),Credit decimal(10,2),Debit decimal(10,2),Result decimal(10,2)
,ExpectedOP VARCHAR(20))

insert into @Test (Credit,Debit,ExpectedOP)
select 10,5,'2.00' union
select 0,2,'0' union
select 5,6,'0.83' union
select 3.09,7,'3.09'

SELECT * , CAST(Credit AS FLOAT) newCredit FROM @test
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ID          Credit   Debit      Result      ExpectedOP           newCredit
----------- ------------------- ----------- -------------------- ----------------------
1           0.00     2.00       NULL        0                    0
2           3.09     7.00       NULL        3.09                 3.09
3           5.00     6.00       NULL        0.83                 5
4           10.00    5.00       NULL        2.00                 10

(4 rows affected)
```